# Extjs4 store filter - search within string

Tags: filter, extjs4, store

In extjs store filter function is as follows:

store.filter(filters, value);      which is =>    store.filter(column name, string to search);

the value is matched with store values serially, IE if I have to search "bc" in "abcd"  it will not find it but it will match when I give ab because abcd starts with ab.

How can I filter values withing string during store filter, I want to get all results which match within string as well, not just start of string.

Answer (score 3):

Use a custom filter function. Below is an untested example:

```
var myfilter = new Ext.util.Filter({
    filterFn: function(rec) {
        return rec.get('columnname').indexOf('bc') > -1;
    }
});

store.filter(myfilter);
```

Or use the filterBy method.

```
store.filterBy(function(rec){
            return rec.get('columnname').indexOf('bc') > -1;
        }
    });
```

Comment: And what should be the regEx ?

Comment: I have updated the examples to use indexOf() method. It should be straight forward.

Comment: If you want to use regular expression searching, that's easy too.
var regex = /bc/;
store.filterBy(function(rec){
    return regex.test(rec.get("columnname"));
});